# I have two M3U8 files that can be played, but don't have URLs in them. Why?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-streaming

Here are the files; [Z05_USEng.m3u8](https://www.nintendo.co.jp/pikpiksecret/movie/pikmin3_Zmovie_USEng/Z05_USEng/Z05_USEng.m3u8) and [Z05_JPJpn.m3u8](https://www.nintendo.co.jp/pikpiksecret/movie/pikmin3_Zmovie_JPJpn/Z05_JPJpn/Z05_JPJpn.m3u8).
I can use the command `ffmpeg -i x -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50 file.mp4`
, with x being the URL to the m3u8, to download the MP4 data to a file. I can also use VLC to play the stream. What I don't understand is how I can do these two things when all the files contain is

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1696000
Z05_USEng/Z05_USEng.m3u8
```

(with UsEng being replaced with JpJpn in the second file).

Comment: `-vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50` does not make sense. The first option says "copy the video stream", the second option says "copy video, audio, and subtitle streams", and the third option says "use the CRF=50 parameter", which will be used when re-encoding the video with libx264. Do you want to just re-mux? Or re-encode the file? ([CRF 50 is horrible quality](http://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html), not sure where you got that from.)

Comment: that wasn't my command, I just got one from another answer. thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the contents of the M3U8 file, it lists another M3U8 file, which actually indexes the files to be played:

```
$ curl https://www.nintendo.co.jp/pikpiksecret/movie/pikmin3_Zmovie_USEng/Z05_USEng/Z05_USEng.m3u8
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1696000
Z05_USEng/Z05_USEng.m3u8

$ curl https://www.nintendo.co.jp/pikpiksecret/movie/pikmin3_Zmovie_USEng/Z05_USEng/Z05_USEng/Z05_USEng.m3u8
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10,
Z05_USEng-1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
Z05_USEng-2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
Z05_USEng-3.ts
#EXTINF:8,
Z05_USEng-4.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

These individual MPEG-2 TS files will be downloaded and concatenated based on the second M3U8 file.

Note that

```
ffmpeg -i <url> -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c copy file.mp4
```

will suffice if you do not want to re-encode the video or audio streams.

Comment: thank you! i didn't realise that was a subdirectory. thanks for the correct command, you are right - I didn't want to reencode the video.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are subfolders in that directory with Z05_USEng/Z05_USEng.m3u8 files inside, try looking inside them for clues

Comment: that directory isn't browsable, but I see from slhck's answer that the folder listed in the m3u8 is in fact another folder with the same name inside the folder that the m3u8 is in. thanks anyway.